# Bootstrap en Laravel

Tags: laravel, bootstrap

Me gustaría saber como puedo ejecutar Bootstrap en solo una sección de Laravel, ya que, si lo coloco en general, se me desconfigura toda la página!

[image: Página con Bootstrap Añadido]

Acá está el bootstrap añadido, pero, se desconfigura toda la página, se mueven los botones y demas!

Sin bootstrap se vería algo así

[image: Más ordenado]

No sé como ejecutarlo solo en la sección que dice "Featured" para poder realizar filtros para el gráfico que se muestra ahí

De ante mano, muchas gracias

Comment: Utiliza el [CDN](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/download/) de bootstrap solo en la página que necesites, porque si instalas con todo y dependencias a través de la consola, se aplicará para todo tu proyecto.

Comment: Ya lo intenté, pero no me funcionó

Comment: Como dice cris, usas el cdn, pero créate un nuevo app.blade solo para esa página que contendrá una copia de la estructura del html de tu proyecto, la diferencia con este es que tendrá el bootstrap que quieres

Answer (score 1):

Como comentaron los compañeros, es muy difícil darte una solución que no sea laboriosa.

Para mí tienes dos opciones:

1. Utilizar Bootstrap solo en ésta página añadiendo el [CDN](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/download/) de Bootstrap. Y arreglándolo con cuidado en una hoja de estilos que sólo utilices ahí. En esa hoja de estilos irás arreglando las reglas CSS que hacen que tu proyecto se vea mal. Ésta opción va a ser la mejor porque luego, de a poco, la puedes ir completando para poder utilizar ese CSS en todo el sitio y arreglar el problema definitivamente.
2. Segunda opción: En esa ruta incluyes un iFrame que mande a llamar el bloque de la gráfica que deseas. De esa forma el CSS del iFrame no influirá en el CSS de tu sitio completo.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente parece que la plantilla original es incompatible con las reglas CSS de Bootstrap. Una solución posible sería revisar, con las herramientas de desarrollo, cada una de las secciones de la página que se ven afectadas por ciertas reglas de Bootstrap, y sobreescribir las reglas de Bootstrap con reglas propias en un CSS incluido después de Bootstrap, evitando que el diseño original se vea alterado.